# Looking for a specific quotation, from Ted, about his wife Stacy

Tags: dialogue, better-off-ted

In the series Better Off Ted, the protagonist often refers to his ex-wife.

On at least one occasion (maybe two), he describes her work, saying something along the lines of: "she's working on improving the world, instead of her self. which is not working out very well, either for her or for the world".

Does anyone have the original quote, preferably with a few lines before and after, preferably with a reference to an online source (if available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - it was in the pilot, per the other answer:

> When Rose was four, her mom left us to go save the world. That's been hard for Rose. Frankly, not so great for the world, either.

([see here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=better-off-ted-2009&episode=s01e01) for full transcript)

Answer (score 2):

There is a modest collection of quotes from every episode [here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Better_Off_Ted), though I don't see any related to that one.

From what I can find, Ted mentions it in passing in the pilot to establish that he is single and has sole custody of Rose.  According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1346400/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl), the line is closer to *She left me to find herself and save the world*.